# Better way to rotate index back to first element in `for` loop with enumerate() in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, enumeration

I hope more experienced users in Python will be able to help me make this more efficient:

If I need cyclic operations, for example if the last element of an array needs to be connected to the first element in an enumerated loop, is there a better way to do this than the following?

```
foo=['tic', 'tac', 'toe']
for i, v in enumerate(foo):
    if i<len(foo)-1:
        print(i, v,foo[i+1])
    else:
        print(i, v,foo[0])
```

This elementary method will get more complicated if more than one element rolling is required let's say to get such a result:

```
 0 tic tac toe
 1 tac toe tic  
 2 toe tic tac
```

Speaking of rolling, I looked into **numpy.roll** but that seems to be creating new arrays (I think?) which I am trying to avoid if possible.

Please note that this could be something such as `sin(foo[i])*foo[i+1]` or other complicated calculations that need a connection back to the first elements and this example from the pyhton.org website may be misleading as I am not looking for permutations.

Comment: `foo.append( foo.pop(0) )` is a pretty easy solution.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks, I am trying to avoid creating new arrays if possible.

Comment: That statement does not create a new array.

Comment: @TimRoberts it doesn't? Maybe it's my lack of knowledge in Python but usually Append operations create a new array in memory. Also if that is the way to do it there's no need to 'pop .()' and one can just use 'foo.append(foo[0])' or even better numpy.roll for more elements but I still think that creates new arrays in the memory because the appended object is not the same as original array

Comment: `append` does not create a new object.  That's the point, as opposed to, say, `foo = foo + [foo[0]]`, which creates two lists and destroys two.  Remember, lists (unlike tuples and string) can be modified.  And `foo.append(foo[0])` would cause the array to grow in size infinitely.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that about append.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with slicing. This will work with any array size

```
foo = ['tic', 'tac', 'toe']
for i in range(len(foo)):
    print(i, ' '.join(foo[i:] + foo[:i]))
```

Output

```
0 tic tac toe
1 tac toe tic
2 toe tic tac
```

Comment: This is good and promising! I specially like it because the vectorized nature of slicing is supposed to be pretty fast and better than making changes to the array, right?

Comment: @MathX yes, slicing should be faster than modifying the list.

Comment: Wait was there a version of your answer that had `enumerate` in it?

Comment: @MathX You don't need `enumerate` here, this solution slice the list by indices. If you insist on doing so (again, I don't think you should) you can use `for i, _ in enumerate(foo):`.

Comment: I do need `enumerate` to make my life easier and avoid rewriting a ton of code. But still  your response works, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

whenever you go circular on a linear range, I try to think of modular arithmetic

```py
foo=['tic', 'tac', 'toe', 'baz', 'bar']

roll_factor = 2

for i in range(len(foo)):
    print(foo[(i + roll_factor) % len(foo)])
```

you can change `roll_factor` for rolling more than one element

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to use it in enumerate to avoid `range(len(foo))` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not aware if enumerate can help with rolling back to first element

Comment: Still, I appreciate your response, it gives me ideas for some occasion.